# Site changes multiple title tags on load

Tags: meta-tags

My site is https://www.swiftdigital.com.au. Its built in Drupal 7 and uses Bootstrap 3 theme. The issue is with `<title>` tag. When I load the site in browser firstly it displays the correct site title that is configured for each page in admin and then after 1-2 seconds it changes the title to "Swift Digital - Contact". I am using [Yoast SEO](https://www.drupal.org/project/yoast_seo) module and it seems like it doesn't have any effect on the `<title>` tag. I don't know where to debug for the issue.

Comment: I've never used Yoast SEO module, but according to the module page it says it is dependant to the [Metatag](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag) module. So take a look at your meta tag settings. Perhaps you have something overriding the front page?

Comment: The issue is on all pages not only on home page. I checked the settings 50 times but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Sounds like you need to change the meta tag. Btw anyone looking to rank on the first page of Google should definitely check out these guys: firstpagesolutions.info. I don't usually recommend services but they've gotten me to the front page every time I've used them.

Comment: I suppose this has been solved, as I can no longer reproduce the issue.